# oracle sql conditional where statement

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I am having trouble with the where statement of the following SQL query:

```
select distinct
  [columns]
from ifsapp.customer_order_inv_head coih
left outer join ifsapp.identity_invoice_info iii
  on coih.company = iii.company
  and coih.identity = iii.identity
  and iii.party_type_db = 'CUSTOMER'
left outer join ifsapp.customer_info_address cia
  on coih.identity = cia.customer_id
  and cia.address_id = '1' 
left outer join ifsapp.customer_info_comm_method cicm
  on coih.identity = cicm.customer_id
  and cicm.address_id = '1'
where coih.invoice_date between to_date('&date_from', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('&date_to',        'dd/mm/yyyy')
  and iii.group_id not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
  and iii.pay_term_id <> 'SO'
  and ifsapp.fb_dev_utils_api.is_einvoice_customer(coih.identity) = 'FALSE'
  and ifsapp.fb_dev_utils_api.is_edi_customer(coih.identity) = 'FALSE'
  and coih.net_amount >= ('&Value')
  and upper(cicm.name) not like upper(nvl('&Optout', 'blank'))
  and upper(iii.group_id) like upper(nvl('&Cust_Group', '%'))
  and upper(coih.company) like upper(nvl('&Company', '%'))
```

The above works fine (if a tad slow), however I also want to exclude `iii.group_id = '10'` only if `coih.contract not like 'S%'` but I cannot get the syntax right. I have tried the following:

```
or (coih.contract not like 'S%' and iii.group_id = '10')
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
OR (coih.contract NOT LIKE 'S%' AND iii.group_id = '10')
```

Try this:

```
AND NOT (coih.contract LIKE 'S%' AND iii.group_id = '10')
```

This way it will look at whether the group_id is equal to 10 and the contract does not begin with 'S'.

Comment: I only want group_id 10 to be returned if the contract is not like 'S%', however I want all the other group_ids to be returned regardless of the contract.

The solution above behaves correctly if the group_id is 10 but excludes all other group_ids.

Comment: As Gordon has already specified I see no reason why this would not work

AND NOT (coih.contract NOT LIKE 'S%' AND iii.group_id = '10')

Comment: I either missed the `and not...` or the answer was edited after I wrote my comment either way I thank you both for your assistance.

Comment: These answers are not quite right but have allowed me a to get to a solution:

`AND NOT (coih.contract LIKE 'S%' AND iii.group_id = '10')`

Comment: Glad you got a solution, it's very hard to figure out what a user wants especially when you can't run the code yourself. I have edited my answer to reflect what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are sort of on the right track.  But the `where` statement is about what to *include*, not *exclude*.  You want to include records like:

```
and (coih.contract like 'S%' or iii.group_id <> '10')
```

You might find this form a bit easier to follow:

```
and not (coih.contract not like 'S%' and iii.group_id = '10')
```

By the way, this assumes that the two variables do not take on NULL values.